# Bulk download facebook videos

Tags: download, automation, facebook

I have a .txt with direct links to 154 facebook video's in it, which i'd love to download in .mp4 or some such format.

Format is like this:
https://www.facebook.com/LesnarUFC/videos/677753912371587/

Anyone know of a way I can do this in bulk or any software which will do it? I tried keepvid which wasn't very good, and would not accept bulk. I don't mind having to pay for the software, or if I can programmatically do it. Suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: From a [related question](http://superuser.com/q/168622/348859) that was closed for being off-topic b/c it was specifically asking for software recommendation, there are comments that point you to `wget`. If you're on Windows, it's available [here](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gnuwin32/wget-1.11.4-1-bin.zip) and make sure you extract it's [dependencies](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gnuwin32/wget-1.11.4-1-dep.zip) to the same folder.

Comment: There is no direct file download i can wget that i can see, this is what my main issue is, i have tried to use this approach.

Comment: @heidisievert - [Yes](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) there is.  I had no problem finding it when I had to write a script to download CSV from a website recently.

Comment: Ah, I see. You have a link to the page with an embedded video and you want need the video URL to download the file using wget? If the videos are always in the same place on the screen, you can use AutoHotkey to load each page, right-click on the video, copy the URL, and save that into a log file, finally using wget based on that log instead. I meantion AHK only because I'm comfortable with it. It may be the best solution to get the video URLs directly, though, and right-clicking on the video or inspecting the element are the only ways I know to do that.

Answer (score 0):

First take a look at http://www.dowfb.com

Or use do these steps:

1. Opend your links in a text editer
2. Replace all links width into html links formats like `<a download href="{VideoLink}"></a>`
3. Save this file in html format like "myBulkVideos.html"
4. Open this file in your browser
5. Open "Developper Mode" by typing on F12
6. Go to console Tab
7. And execute this code: 
   `var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){links[i].click()}`

This code will trigger click events on all of your videos links

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`youtube-dl` utility](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) for that, it supports Facebook videos as well.

After installing, simply run:

```
youtube-dl "https://www.facebook.com/FacebookUK/videos/242001450001180/"
```

It should also work for non-public videos after providing your user credentials.

See also: [How can I download non public Facebook video?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58690/22759)

Answer (score 0):

4K Video Downloader: This is a paid software that allows you to download multiple videos at once from various websites including YouTube, Vimeo, and more